# How do I convert a class method into a relation between two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, associations, relation

I have the model `BasePlan` that `has_many` `Plan`s. We use a class method in `BasePlan` to order associated `Plan`s alphabetically, and I need to refactor that into an association between the two models.

*`BasePlan` class:*

```
has_many :plans, -> { extending BuildWithAccount },
           inverse_of: :base_plan, dependent: :destroy
```

*`Plan` class:*

```
belongs_to  :base_plan
```

*`BasePlan` class method to order Plans alphabetically:*

```
  def order_plans_alphabetically
    plans.order(code: :asc)
  end
```

I created a new association in `BasePlan` like so:

```
has_many :alphabetically_ordered_plans, -> { order_plans_alphabetically }, class_name: "Plan"
```

Which results in:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `order_plans_alphabetically' for #<Plan::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005593e3876460>
```

I also tried including the class method in the existing association's `lambda` resulting in more than 100 tests failing so I don't think that's the way to go either.

What would be an effective way to refactor the class method into a relationship between the two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :alphabetically_ordered_plans, 
  -> { order(code: :asc) # short for Plan.order(code: :asc) }, 
  class_name: "Plan"
```

The context that the lambda is evaluatated in is not the BasePlan clas) rather its the class that your associating (Plan). If you really want to use a scope (basically just a class method) you need to place it in that class:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :base_plan
  scope :order_by_code, ->{ order(code: :asc) }
end

class BasePlan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :alphabetically_ordered_plans, 
    -> { order_by_code },
    class_name: "Plan"
end
```